# Mathematica crashes when moving cursor too fast between cells

Tags: front-end, crash

Sometimes Mathematica crashes when I move the cursor too fast between cells. 
The FrontEnd becomes unresponsive, and the only solution is to close the window. 
I have experienced this problem on three different machines.

Any ideas? Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: [Support](https://support.wolfram.com/12507) is going to be where you’d take an issue like this. You should be sure to follow the directions on the linked page. Out of curiosity, what version is this you’re using? And are these issues occurring with a fresh kernel and new notebook? In addition to sating my curiosity, you should also include this information when you contact support to solve this issue.

Comment: May be this is Mathematica's way telling you to just slow down and no need to rush :)

Comment: I experienced issues like this in versions 11.x, running on Ubuntu Linux. I have had much less trouble in this regard with version 12.

Comment: I am using version 12.1, running on Windows 10. Sometimes it happens with a fresh notebook, and others after many calculations.